# 401 Unauthorized exception throws on Sharepoint Webpart using DataContext

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, web-parts, datacontext

I'm using the below code to create a new instance of Sharepoint datacontext:

```
spDataContext con = new spDataContext(new Uri("http://mysite/subsite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc"));
con.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Then I try fetching the items by using

```
var result = con.testingList.ToList();
```

Then Below error shows:

> "401 UNAUTHORIZED"

Here's the screenshot of the error:

[image]

But if I change the credentials by providing the sharepoint admin username and password, I am able to fetch the items.

```
con.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(username, password);
```

But the problem is: I want to use the current user's credentials instead of administrator account, since not all the items are supposed to be seen by current user.

Some addition information from the IIS:

[image]

At first, all authentication methods are enabled, then I tried turning off basic and digest authentication to see if it helps, but the exception still throws.

So how to fix this problem??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last the reason was:

I don't have the System.Web assembly in the class library, so the system was unable to get the CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check what account you are actually connecting with by inspecting a breakpoint, writing to a log or checking the server's audit trail/Logs (IIS/SharePoint) - are you sure it's a valid account and not an IUSR_xyz IIS account or something like that? Also check that you are not hitting a [Kerberos "double hop"](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/) if you are working with a distributed architecture. This can often trip you up when adding another server/service to the mix.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately, due to the security reasons, I am unable to inspect which account I'm connecting to in debug mode, they'll display empty. For the double hop part, I'll take a deeper look next morning ~

Comment: That sounds peculiar - it's likely a security issue somewhere in your ecosystem - with limited privilege it will be hard to troubleshoot. Can you get someone with the relevant system permissions to work with you on it? Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this to work, you should configure the `Authentication` options in IIS as follows:

- Anonymous Authentication - **DISABLED**
- ASPNET Impersonation - **DISABLED**
- Windows Authentication - **ENABLED**

You can use the `CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials`, but I would suggest switching from using the WCF services to using CSOM (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client).

Comment: I've set the IIS Authentication as you said, but the 401 still exists... Also, is CSOM same as CAML?

Comment: no CSOM is a SharePoint object model that enables you to do the operations that you would used to need the web services to accomplish in previous SharePoint releases. more info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179912.aspx

Comment: Also make sure you are authorized to access the services you are trying to reference.

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look in the next morning